# Burninate [delphi-berlin]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

Correct name for this tag (a valid delphi version name) is [delphi-10.1-berlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi-10.1-berlin).

I replaced all [delphi-berlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi-berlin) tags (a handful or two) with [delphi-10.1-berlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi-10.1-berlin), so can we burninate this tag, please?

Comment: If there's no question in it it should just disappear, no?

Comment: @Kyll, unless a less experienced user pick this tag by mistake again, for the grace period of an empty tag.

Comment: If the tag gets revived, we should just make it a synonym.